# C# Unit tests - Unable to extract Content from the IHttpActionResult responce

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have this controller

```
    [Route("GeocacheAddressObjectList")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GeocacheAddressObjectList([FromBody] List<GeocacheAddress> addresses)
    {
        //check valid addresses
        if(addresses == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid addresses. The address list object is null!") as IHttpActionResult;
        }

        ElasticHelper searchHelper = new ElasticHelper(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticSearchUri"]);
        List<GeocacheAddress> geocodedAddresses = new List<GeocacheAddress>();

        // check each address in the addresses list against geocache db
        foreach (GeocacheAddress address in addresses)
        {
            var elasticSearchResult = SearchGeocacheIndex(address);

            // found a match
            if (elasticSearchResult.Total != 0)
            {
                SearchProperties standardizedAddressSearch = new SearchProperties();
                standardizedAddressSearch.Size = 1;
                standardizedAddressSearch.From = 0;

                Address elasticSearchResultAddress = elasticSearchResult.Hits.ElementAt(0).Source;

                // query the standardized key in geocache db
                standardizedAddressSearch.ElasticAddressId = elasticSearchResultAddress.Standardized.ToString();

                // the address is already standardized, return the standardized address with its geocode
                if (standardizedAddressSearch.ElasticAddressId == "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
                {
                    geocodedAddresses.Add(new GeocacheAddress
                    {
                        Id = address.Id,
                        Street = elasticSearchResultAddress.AddressString,
                        City = elasticSearchResultAddress.City,
                        State = elasticSearchResultAddress.State,
                        ZipCode = elasticSearchResultAddress.Zipcode,
                        Plus4Code = elasticSearchResultAddress.Plus4Code,
                        Country = elasticSearchResultAddress.Country,
                        Latitude = elasticSearchResultAddress.Coordinates.Lat,
                        Longitude = elasticSearchResultAddress.Coordinates.Lon
                    });
                }
                else // perform another query using the standardized key
                {
                    Address standardizedAddress = StandardAddressSearch(standardizedAddressSearch).Hits.ElementAt(0).Source;
                    if (standardizedAddress == null)
                    {
                        return BadRequest("No standardized address found in geocache database") as IHttpActionResult;
                    }

                    geocodedAddresses.Add(new GeocacheAddress()
                    {
                        Id = address.Id,
                        Street = standardizedAddress.AddressString,
                        City = standardizedAddress.City,
                        State = standardizedAddress.State,
                        ZipCode = standardizedAddress.Zipcode,
                        Plus4Code = standardizedAddress.Plus4Code,
                        Country = standardizedAddress.Country,
                        Latitude = standardizedAddress.Coordinates.Lat,
                        Longitude = standardizedAddress.Coordinates.Lon
                    });
                }
            }
            else // not found in geocache db, call SmartStreets API
            {
                List<Address> address_list = new List<Address>();

                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //Send the request and get the response
                    httpClient.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GeocodingServiceUri"]);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    //Lookup object to perform Geocoding service call
                    var postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Lookup()
                    {
                        MaxCandidates = 1,
                        Street = address.Street,
                        City = address.City,
                        State = address.State,
                        ZipCode = address.ZipCode
                    });

                    var requestContent = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    // Send the request and get the response
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("GeocodeAddressObject", requestContent);

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) //error handling
                    {
                        geocodedAddresses.Add(new GeocacheAddress()
                        {
                            Id = address.Id,
                            Error = response.ReasonPhrase
                        });

                    }

                    Geocode geocodeFromGeocoder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Geocode>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).ElementAt(0);

                    GeocacheAddress geocodedAddress = new GeocacheAddress()
                    {
                        Id = address.Id,
                        Street = geocodeFromGeocoder.CorrectedAddress,
                        City = geocodeFromGeocoder.City,
                        State = geocodeFromGeocoder.State,
                        ZipCode = geocodeFromGeocoder.Zipcode,
                        Plus4Code = geocodeFromGeocoder.Plus4Code,
                        Country = geocodeFromGeocoder.Country,
                        Latitude = geocodeFromGeocoder.Latitude,
                        Longitude = geocodeFromGeocoder.Longitude
                    };

                    geocodedAddresses.Add(geocodedAddress);

                    // check each geocoded address against geocache db
                    Guid standardized_key;

                    var geocodedAddressResult = SearchGeocacheIndex(geocodedAddress);

                    // found a match
                    if (geocodedAddressResult.Total != 0)
                    {
                        Address standardizedAddress = geocodedAddressResult.Hits.ElementAt(0).Source;
                        standardized_key = standardizedAddress.AddressID;
                    }
                    else // not found, insert geocode into geocache db
                    {
                        Address new_standardized_address = createStandardizedAddress(geocodeFromGeocoder);
                        standardized_key = new_standardized_address.AddressID;

                        address_list.Add(new_standardized_address);
                    }

                    // insert non-standardized address into geocache db
                    Address new_nonstandardized_address = createNonStandardizedAddress(address, standardized_key);
                    address_list.Add(new_nonstandardized_address);
                }

                searchHelper.BulkIndex<Address>(address_list, "xxx", "xxx");
            }
        }
        return Json(geocodedAddresses, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()) as IHttpActionResult;
    }
```

I am writing a unit test to test some part of this controller.

I want to compare the response received from the controller with the expected value. When i debug the result, it shows the content for the response but I am unable to use content like (result.Content) in the code.

When i try to use this line, then it returns null response.

```
        var result = await controller.GeocacheAddressObjectList(testGeocacheAddress) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<GeocacheAddress>;
```

Actual unit test code. I would appreciate any help.

```
  [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
        var controller = new GeocachingController();

        var testGeocacheAddress = new List<GeocacheAddress>();
        testGeocacheAddress.Add(new GeocacheAddress
        {
            City = "Renton",
        });

        var result = await controller.GeocacheAddressObjectList(testGeocacheAddress);

        var expected = GetGeocacheAddress();

        Assert.AreEqual(result.Content.City, expected[0].City);
```

}

```
private List<GeocacheAddress> GetGeocacheAddress()
    {
        var testGeocacheAddress = new List<GeocacheAddress>();
        testGeocacheAddress.Add(new GeocacheAddress
        {
            Id = Guid.Empty,
            Street = "365 Renton Center Way SW",
            City = "Renton",
            State = "WA",
            ZipCode = "98057",
            Plus4Code = "2324",
            Country = "USA",
            Latitude = 47.47753,
            Longitude = -122.21851,
            Error = null
        });

        return testGeocacheAddress;
    }
```

Comment: When you're using the 'as' keyword it is attempting to convert the object you give it to the type you specify. It is failing to convert and returning null instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your unit test you need to cast the result to `JsonResult<T>`, more specifically `JsonResult<List<GeocacheAddress>>` as that is what you are returning.

```
var result = await controller.GeocacheAddressObjectList(testGeocacheAddress) as JsonResult<List<GeocacheAddress>>;
```

---

If you were to have used `return Ok(geocodedAddresses)` in your controller return (*where you now return the call from `Json`*) then you could have cast to `OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<GeocacheAddress>>`.

---

Also in your Controller code you do not need to cast the return to `IHttpActionResult` because `JsonResult<T>` already implements that. The cast is redundant.

Comment: Your suggestion worked as a charm. Thank you so much for the response.

Answer (score 2):

That's quite simple to achieve, all you have to do is cast the content you're expecting in your unit test method.

Example:

Controller:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var foo = "foo";
            return Ok(foo);
        }
    }
```

Unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Get_Foo_From_Controller()
    {
        var fooController = new FooController();
        var result = fooController.Get();
        //Here we are casting the expected type
        var values = (OkNegotiatedContentResult<string>)result;
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo", values.Content);
    }
```

By the way, i noticed you're using the async keyword in your controller action but i don't see the await keyword.

Using the async keyword without an await will give you a warning and result in a **synchronous** operation.

Also, you dont have to cast your response as an IHttpActionResult, you could do something like i showed in my example, wrap your content inside an Ok(your content here) and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Really appreciate it. I`ll remove casting it to IHttpActionResult and add the keyword async.